# Error 'An object was provided as `children` instead of a component....' appears on dashboard

Tags: plotly-dash

sample csv data:

> date,Data Center,Customer,companyID,source,target,value

I run below code for put the sankey chart in dashboard, and the chart can be updated accordingly by applying filters. but an error appears on dashboard. What is the issue?

> An object was provided as `children` instead of a component, string,
> or number (or list of those). Check the children property that looks
> something like:

```py
    import io
from base64 import b64encode
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as pio
import pandas as pd

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

colors = {
    'background': '#111111',
    'text': '#7FDBFF'
}

dataset = pd.read_csv('leanSankey.csv')

labelListTemp1 = list(set(dataset.source.values))
labelListTemp2 = list(set(dataset.target.values))
labelList = labelListTemp1 + labelListTemp2
sankey_node = list(dict.fromkeys(labelList))
 
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey( node = dict( pad=15,thickness=20,line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),label = labelList,color = 'black' ),
                                 link = dict(source = dataset.source.apply(lambda x: labelList.index(x)),
                                             target = dataset.target.apply(lambda x: labelList.index(x)),
                                             value = dataset.value))])

#fig.update_layout(autosize=False,width = 3000,height = 1000,hovermode = 'x',title="test user behavior monitor",font=dict(size=16, color='blue'))
    
#fig.write_html('test.html', auto_open=True)
#fig.show()



app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dataCenter_dropdown',
        options=[ {'label': i, 'value': i} for i in dataset['Data Center'].unique()] + [{'label': 'Select all', 'value': 'allID'}],
        multi=True, placeholder='Please select Data Center'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='customer_dropdown',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in dataset['Customer'].unique()]  + [{'label': 'Select all', 'value': 'allID'}],
        multi=True, placeholder='Please select Customer'),
    
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='companyID_dropdown',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in dataset['companyID'].unique()] + [{'label': 'Select all', 'value': 'allID'}],
        multi=True, placeholder='Please select companyID'),
    
    
#    html.Div(id='dd-output-container'),
     dcc.Graph(id='uxrPerfGoalSankey',figure=fig)
])

@app.callback(
#    Output('dd-output-container', 'children'),
    Output('uxrPerfGoalSankey', 'figure'),
    [Input('dataCenter_dropdown', 'value'),
     Input('customer_dropdown', 'value'),
     Input('companyID_dropdown', 'value')])


def update_graph(dataCenter, customer, companyID):

    if dataCenter=='Select all' and customer=='Select all' and companyID=='Select all':
        df=dataset.copy()
    else:
        df = dataset.loc[dataset['Data Center'].isin([dataCenter]) & dataset['Customer'].isin([customer]) & dataset['companyID'].isin([companyID])]
    
    labelListTemp1 = list(set(df.source.values))
    labelListTemp2 = list(set(df.target.values))
    labelList = labelListTemp1 + labelListTemp2
    sankey_node = list(dict.fromkeys(labelList))
    
    fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Sankey( node = dict( pad=15,thickness=20,line = dict(color = "black", width = 0.5),label = labelList,color = "blue" ),
                                     link = dict(source = df.source.apply(lambda x: labelList.index(x)),
                                                 target = df.target.apply(lambda x: labelList.index(x)),
                                                 value = df.value))])
    return fig
    
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your callback function returns a `figure` and is trying to assign it to the `children` property of a `html.Div`. Can't do that as far as I know. A div's child should be other components, strings or numbers as stated in the error message.

Did you mean to write

```
Output('uxrPerfGoalSankey', 'figure'),
```

instead?

If not and you need to return a new fig to that div, create a `dcc.Graph` inside your div and return that graphs's figure value instead.

Edit:

You also overwrite your input values right at the top of your callback function. No matter what you select, the df is ultimately filtered by the same values. I.E. you select dataCenter 'A' in your dropdown but in the first line you set dataCenter to dataframe['Data Center'], so what was the point of selecting one? If that's not intended, delete those assignments?

One imminent pitfall by the way: multi dropdowns pass **either** a single value **or** a list of values. To make your df selection consistent, force all the inputs to be lists:

```
if not isinstance(dataCenter, list):
    dataCenter = [dataCenter]
# etc
```

Edit 2:

The issue was how you handle the parameters being lists vs single values and the selection of 'select all'. I adjusted the logic to treat 'None' (dd selection empty) and 'Select all' as all values selected. If you don't want to plot anything when a selection is empty, do this instead:

```
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
```

...

And then first thing in your callback function:

```
if dataCenter is None or customer is None or companyID is None:
    raise PreventUpdate
```

Anyway here's the code with the logic as I described it:

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']
app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

colors = {
    'background': '#111111',
    'text': '#7FDBFF'
}

dataset = pd.read_csv('values.csv')


def generate_graph(df):

    labels = list(set(df.source.values)) + list(set(df.target.values))

    fig = go.Figure(data=[
        go.Sankey(node=dict(pad=15, thickness=20, line=dict(color="black", width=0.5), label=labels, color="blue"),
                  link=dict(source=df.source.apply(lambda x: labels.index(x)),
                            target=df.target.apply(lambda x: labels.index(x)),
                            value=df.value))
    ])

    return fig


app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dataCenter_dropdown',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in dataset['Data Center'].unique()] + [
            {'label': 'Select all', 'value': 'allID'}],
        multi=True, placeholder='Please select Data Center'),
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='customer_dropdown',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in dataset['Customer'].unique()] + [
            {'label': 'Select all', 'value': 'allID'}],
        multi=True, placeholder='Please select Customer'),

    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='companyID_dropdown',
        options=[{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in dataset['companyID'].unique()] + [
            {'label': 'Select all', 'value': 'allID'}],
        multi=True, placeholder='Please select companyID'),

    dcc.Graph(id='uxrPerfGoalSankey', figure=generate_graph(dataset))
])


@app.callback(
    Output('uxrPerfGoalSankey', 'figure'),
    [Input('dataCenter_dropdown', 'value'),
     Input('customer_dropdown', 'value'),
     Input('companyID_dropdown', 'value')])
def update_graph(dataCenter, customer, companyID):

    if dataCenter is None or len(dataCenter) == 0 or 'allID' in dataCenter:
        dataCenter = dataset['Data Center']
    elif not isinstance(dataCenter, list):
        dataCenter = [dataCenter]

    if customer is None or len(customer) == 0 or 'allID' in customer:
        customer = dataset['Customer']
    elif not isinstance(customer, list):
        customer = [customer]

    if companyID is None or len(companyID) == 0 or 'allID' in companyID:
        companyID = dataset['companyID']
    elif not isinstance(companyID, list):
        companyID = [companyID]

    df = dataset[
        (dataset['Data Center'].isin(dataCenter)) &
        (dataset['Customer'].isin(customer)) &
        (dataset['companyID'].isin(companyID))
        ]

    return generate_graph(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Runs fine for me, let me know if any other issues arise.

Comment: Yes and I have adopt your advice with replace 'Output('dd-output-container', 'children')' to 'Output('uxrPerfGoalSankey', 'figure'),' and  update the latest code in post. Now the error has gone and the dashboard is running without error. But when i select values in the filters, the chart doesn't updated accordingly. Do I miss anything else in the callback and update function?

Comment: I updated my answer, does that fix it?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried again(latest code for callback and update_graph function has been updated in post.). But this time I have only 3 filters returned on dashboard, no graph displayed.

Comment: I think at this point I'll need some dummy data to debug

Comment: Thank you. i add some sample csv data in the post.

Comment: Sure, no problem. I added working code to the solution.

Comment: The anwser is accepted. Thanks a lot! Now the filter and dashboard running well. I have tested the dashboard and observed there's a bug for filter function. For example, when I select a value in data center filter, the sankey chart is updated successfully, But after I remove the selected value, the sankey chart is not shown. The expected result should be the sankey chart should be returned with full dataset because the selected filter is removed. is it able to fix?

Comment: I didn't realize that after clearing a selection, the type doesn't go back to None. I added another condition to the if blocks.